Why do I get a wrong data structure using Module?
I am using Module and reading rawlen.txt files from nb100, nb200 , ... folders. I have written a piece of program to calculate strain and I expect the results to have the following structure:
{{0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, 
{0.00227701}, {0.00678594}, {0.0112949}, {0.0158038}, {0.0203127}, 
{0.0248217}, {0.0293306}, {0.0338395}, {0.0383485}, {0.0428574}}
but it has this structure:
strain={{0.,0.},{1.,0.},{2.,0.},{3.,0.},{4.,0.},{5.,0.},{6.,0.},{7.,0.},{8.,0.},{9.,0.},{10.,0.00227701},{11.,0.00678594},{12.,0.0112949},{13.,0.0158038},{14.,0.0203127},{15.,0.0248217},{16.,0.0293306},{17.,0.0338395},{18.,0.0383485},{19.,0.0428574}}
I have tried to print the strain out of module and it has the correct structure. I don't understand the reason it adds the counting numbers 0. 1. 2. ... and produces strain={{0.,0.},{1.,0.}.. structure.
Can any one help me out with this?
here is the code:
    directory = "/Users/delaram/Desktop/April11";
    folders = FileNames["nb*", directory];
    fol = "nb" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[100, 1000, 100];

    processFil[folderName_String] := 
    Module[{directoryPath, rawlen, rcutoff, rawstrain, strain},
   (*set directory*)
   directoryPath = FileNameJoin[{directory, folderName}];
   SetDirectory[directoryPath];
   (*Reading data from directory*)
    rawlen = Import["len.txt", "Data"];
    (*unit conversion*)
    rcutoff = 6.4633*10^(-10);
    (* strain calculation*)
   rawstrain = rawlen*rcutoff;
   lini = rawstrain[[1]];
   strain = 
   Table[(rawstrain[[i]] - lini)/lini, {i, 1, Length[rawstrain]}];
   Print["strain=", strain];
   (*Exporting results*)
   Export[
  FileNameJoin[{directoryPath, 
  "result" <> StringReplace[folderName, "nb" -> ""] <> ".txt"}], 
  strain, "Table"];
  Return[strain];
      ];

   processFil /@ fol

len.txt (is the input data file imported from each folder (nb100, nb200, ...0 separately
It looks like :
  1000 22.1782
  2000 22.1782
  3000 22.1782
  4000 22.1782
  5000 22.1782
  6000 22.1782
  7000 22.1782
   8000 22.1782
  9000 22.1782
  10000 22.1782
  11000 22.2287
  12000 22.3287
  13000 22.4287
  14000 22.5287
  15000 22.6287
  16000 22.7287
  17000 22.8287
  18000 22.9287
  19000 23.0287
  20000 23.1287


Way too many unknown data here. You need to provide us with something we can work with. Also, what does rawly.txt have to do with anything?

Thank you. I fixed the typo. It was misleading.

When you import your len.txt data, it has a two-dimensional structure. So, all the arithmetic you're doing is being done on tuples, not simple numbers. Since the first "column" is an arithmetic sequence, the particular arithmetic you're doing creates the 0, 1, 2, ... sequence. You could either just strip that column from your strain or you could strip it from your rawlen. Or you could fix it in your Table.
So, you could make this change:
(* old *)
rawlen = Import["len.txt", "Data"];

(* new *)
rawlen = Drop[ImportString[testlen, "Table"], 0, 1];

(I'm not sure how your Import worked with "Data", but I had to use "Table". Also, you could use Take instead of Drop)
Or this change:
(* old *)
Return[strain];

(* new *)
Drop[strain, 0, 1]

(You don't need the explicit Return. Again, you could use Take instead of Drop.)
Or this change:
(* old *)
lini = rawstrain[[1]];
strain = Table[(rawstrain[[i]] - lini)/lini, {i, 1, Length[rawstrain]}];

(* new *)
lini = rawstrain[[1, 2]];
strain = Table[(Take[rawstrain[[i]], -1] - lini)/lini, {i, 1, Length[rawstrain]}];

(Or Drop instead of Take.)

Thank you so much for the complete explanation.
